# Querydsl order by value of parameter in child object

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I have an object that is a sample (severly simplified)

```
class Sample {
    List analysis;
}
```

And the analysis contains a value

```
class Analysis {
    Integer value;
}
```

The sample contains N of these samples and not all of them have values. In Querydsl i want to order the results by the percentage of analysis that has any value.

I've tried this but it does not look like it's counting the number of values.

```
query.orderBy(
    new OrderSpecifier(
        pRequest.getOrder(),
        Expressions.asNumber(qSample.analysis.any().value.isNotNull().count().divide(qSample.analysis.size()) )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
query.orderBy(
    pRequest.getOrder(),
    Expressions.asNumber(
         qSample.analysis.any().value.isNotNull().count().divide(qSample.analysis.size())).asc()
);
```

Comment: It gives me `Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting CLOSE, found 'is' near line 5, column 38`

Comment: Hibernate doesn’t seem to support the subqueries introduced with the any() and size() calls in the order by clause. I suggest you rewrite them to plain subqueries.